# Inner joins vs left joins

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have been using `LEFT JOIN` in all my queries so far and just came across the ability to specify multiple tables in `FROM` which gives the same result. I didn't know you could refer to multiple tables in `from` and do joins in `where`. I used `where` strictly for filtering data and kept `from` to one table.

Where can I learn more about option 2 and when it is more useful? Or should I stick to option 1?

**Option 1: LEFT JOIN**

```
select
f.title,
count(r.rental_id)
from rental r
left join inventory i on i.inventory_id=r.inventory_id
left join film f on f.film_id=i.film_id
Group by title
order by count(r.rental_id) desc
```

**Option 2: JOIN in FROM**

```
select
f.title,
count(r.rental_id)
from film f, rental r, inventory i
where f.film_id=i.film_id
and  i.inventory_id=r.inventory_id
group by 1
order by count(r.rental_id) desc
```

Comment: The first one would be IDENTICAL to the second one if you merely changed `left join` to `inner join` so the only real difference here is that the first is an explicit `left join` and the second is an implicit `inner join`. In other words you will get ALL records from `rental` and only matching records from `inventory` and `film` in the first query and in the second query you will only get records where the join condition (where conditions in this case) are true.

Comment: thanks that helps me equate the different methods of getting the results.

Comment: Plus... Option 1 follows ANSI standards whereas Option 2 hasn't been considered good practice for decades

Comment: LEFT JOIN is short for LEFT OUTER JOIN. (At least, it is in SQL Server.)